# Laravel 5 Global CRUD Class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, crud

Before anyone asks, I've looked into `CRUD` generators and I know all about the `Laravel` Resource routes, but that's not exactly what I'm pulling for here.

What I'm looking to do is create one Route with a couple parameters, and one global class that (uses/extends?) the Model controller for simple `CRUD` operations. We have 20 or so Models and creating a Resource `Controller` for each table would be more time consuming than finding a way to create a global `CRUD` class to handle all "`api`" type calls and any `ajax json` request like a create / update / destroy statement.

So my question is what is the cleanest and best way to structure a class to handle all `CRUD` requests for every `Model` we have without having to have a resource `controller` for every `model`? I've tried researching this and can't seem to find any links except ones to `CRUD` generators and links describing the `laravel Resource route`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to do the following:

1. Add a route for your resource controller:

   ```
   Route::resource('crud', 'CrudController', array('except' => array('create', 'edit')));
   ```
2. Create your crud controller

   ```
   <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
   use App\Models\User;
   use App\Models\Product;
   use Input;

   class CrudController extends Controller
   {
       const MODEL_KEY = 'model';

       protected $modelsMapping = [
           'user' => User::class,
           'product' => Product::class
       ];

       protected function getModel() {
           $modelKey = Input::get(static::MODEL_KEY);
           if (array_key_exists($modelKey, $this->modelsMapping)) {
               return $this->modelsMapping[$modelKey];
           }

           throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid model');
       }

       public function index()
       {
           $model = $this->getModel();
           return $model::all();
       }

       public function store()
       {
           $model = $this->getModel();
           return $model::create(array_except(Input::all(), static::MODEL_KEY));
       }

       public function show($id)
       {
           $model = $this->getModel();
           return $model::findOrFail($id);
       }

       public function update($id)
       {
           $model = $this->getModel();
           $object = $model::findOrFail($id);
           return $object->update(array_except(Input::all(), static::MODEL_KEY));
       }

       public function destroy($id)
       {
           $model = $this->getModel();
           return $model::remove($id);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use your new controller :) You have to pass the **model** parameter that will contain the model key - it must be one of the allowed models in the whitelist. E.g. if you want to get a **User** with **id=5** do

   ```
   GET /crud/5?model=user
   ```

Please keep in mind that it's as simple as possible, you might need to make the code more sophisticated to match your needs.

Please also keep in mind that this code has not been tested - let me know if you see any typos or have some other issues. I'll be more than happy to get it running for you.

Comment: I like this idea. We're creating all of our forms using JSON data, and the javascript is generating them. This works good, the only issue I'm seeing is will there be a way to overwrite the "destroy" method in the model? I'm trying to find a way for all models to kind of inherit these methods, and for laravel to intelligently pick up on what method to use based on the model. So let's say I have a "Patient" model and a "Physician" model. I need it to actually destroy and delete the physicians, but for patients and their data, i just need it to set an "IsDeleted" column to 1.

Comment: It's a security issue to pass a lot through a GET statement for us. So the more we can have laravel intelligently pick up, the better it is for us.

Comment: The CRUD controller is using static methods of your models. If you need to customize the behaviour for one of the models just overwrite that method in the model.

Comment: And for setting isDeleted to 1 - Eloquent's SoftDeletes trait is probably what you need - http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: Ok, I actually like this way. I'll implement it today and let you know how it goes. I wasn't sure how the overwriting would work.

Comment: Also, one more question. Is there a way to return a model object versus having to map out every model? That way I don't have to even worry about mapping out each model?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to get rid of $modelsMapping attribute? Then you'd need to pass namespaced model class name in the URL or concatenate whatever is passed in model with the model namespace, if they are all in the same namespace. E.g. function getModel() { return 'App\Models\' . ucfirst(Input::get('model')); }

Comment: My issue with concatenating the "string" coming through with App\Models\$modelKey is this: syntax error, unexpected '$modelKey' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING). Is there any way to concatenate a namespace with a $_GET statement, or better how would I concatenate and create an object with the key that is coming through the $_GET post?

Comment: I pasted the code for getModel method in my previous comment - use that

Comment: Thanks, Sorry, didn't see that fix to begin with. I really appreciate it. That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to implement CRUD manually, consider to integrate a ready-made datagrid such as [phpGrid](http://phpgrid.com).

Check out integration walkthrough: http://phpgrid.com/example/phpgrid-laravel-5-twitter-bootstrap-3-integration/ No models are required and the code is minimum. It can almost do anything.

A basic working CRUD:

```
// in a controller
public function index()
{
    $dg = new \C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM orders", "orderNumber", "orders");
    $dg->enable_edit("FORM", "CRUD");
    $dg->display(false);

    $grid = $dg -> get_display(true); 

    return view('dashboard', ['grid' => $grid]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need one generic class for all `CRUD` operations and there are many ways to achieve that and one rule for all may not fit but you may try the approach that I'm going to describe now. This is an abstract idea, you need to implement it, so at first, think the `URI` for all CRUD operations. In this case you must follow a convention and it could be something like this:

```
example.com/user/{id?} // get all or one by id (if id is available in the URI)
example.com/user/create // Show an empty form
example.com/user/edit/10 // Show a form populated with User model
example.com/user/save // Create a new User
example.com/user/save/10 // Update an existing User
example.com/user/delete/10 // Delete an existing User
```

In ths case the `user` could be something else to specify the name of the model for example, `example.com/product/create` and keeping that on mind, you need to declare routes as given below:

```
Route::get('/{model}/{id?}', 'CrudController@read');
Route::get('/{model}/create', 'CrudController@create');
Route::get('/{model}/edit/{id}', 'CrudController@edit');
Route::post('/{model}/save/{id?}', 'CrudController@save');
Route::post('/{model}/delete/{id}', 'CrudController@delete');
```

Now, in your `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` file modify the `boot` method and make it look like this:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    $model = null;

    $router->bind('model', function($modelName) use (&$model, &$router)
    {
        $model = app('\App\User\\'.ucfirst($modelName));

        if($model)
        {
            if($id = $router->input('id'))
            {
                $model = $model->find($id);
            }

            return $model ?: abort(404);
        }
    });

    parent::boot($router);
}
```

Then declare your `CrudController` as given below:

```
class CrudController extends Controller
{
    protected $request = null;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function read($model)
    {
        return $model->exists ? $model : $model->all();
    }

    // Show either an empty form or a form
    // populated with the given model atts
    public function createOrEdit($model)
    {
        $classNameArray = explode('\\', get_class($model));

        $className = strtolower(array_pop($classNameArray));

        $view = view($className . '.form');

        $view->formAction = "$className/save";

        if(is_object($model) && $model->exists)
        {
            $view->model = $model;

            $view->formAction .= "/{$model->id}";
        }

        return $view;
    }

    public function save($model)
    {
        // Validation required so do it
        // Make sure each Model has $fillable specified
        return $this->model->fill($this->request)->save();
    }

    public function delete($model)
    {
        return $this->model->delete();
    }
}
```

Since same form is used to creating and updating a model, use something like this to create a form:

```
<form action="{{url($formAction)}}" method="POST">

    <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    name="first_name" value="{{old('first_name', @$model->first_name)}}"
    />
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
    {!!csrf_field()!!}

 </form>
```

Remember that, each form should be in a directory corresponding to the model, for user add/edit, form should be in `views/user/form.blade.php` and for product model use `views/product/form.blade.php` and so on.

This will work and don't forget to add validation before saving a model and validation could be done inside the model using model events or however you want. This is just an idea but probably not the best way to it.

Comment: I was actually looking into Route Model Binding and trying to figure out a way to use this. Big thing is were generating all of our forms in js and using JSON data to generate them on the fly. The "save" / "edit" location for each form though we can modify. After I have my coffee I'm definitely going to take a look at the way this is set as well. Big thing I brought up with @jedrzej.kurylo answer is I need laravel to intelligently pick up the way the model destroys. So I need a way to overwrite the methods in each model and the route to pick up the way the model does this.